# SQLAlchemy ORM - map an object to dynamically created schema

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm considering porting my app to the SQLAlchemy as it's much more extensive than my own ORM implementation, but all the examples I could find show how to set the schema name at class declaration rather than dynamically at runtime.

I need to map my objects to Postgres tables from multiple schemas. Moreover, the application creates new schemas in runtime and I need to map new instances of the class to rows of the table from that new schema.

Currently, I use my own ORM module where I just provide the schema name as an argument when creating new instances of a class (I call class' method with the schema name as an argument and it returns an object(s) that holds the schema name). The class describes a table that can exist in many schemas. The class declaration doesn't contain information about schema, but instances of that class do contain it and include it when generating SQL statements.
This way, the application can work with many schemas simultaneously and even create foreign keys in tables from "other" schemas to the "main" table in the public schema. In such a way it is also possible to delete data in other schemas cascaded when deleting the row in the public schema.

The SQLAlchemy gives this example to set the schema for the table ([documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData)):

```
metadata_obj = MetaData(schema="remote_banks")

financial_info = Table(
    "financial_info",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("value", String(100), nullable=False),
)
```

But on ORM level, when I declare the class, I should pass an already constructed table (example from [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#explicit-schema-name-with-declarative-table)):

```
metadata = MetaData()
group_users = Table(
    "group_users",
    metadata,
    Column("user_id", String(40), nullable=False),
    Column("group_id", String(40), nullable=False),
    UniqueConstraint("user_id", "group_id"),
)


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class GroupUsers(Base):
    __table__ = group_users
    __mapper_args__ = {"primary_key": [group_users.c.user_id, group_users.c.group_id]}
```

So, the question is: is it possible to map class instances to tables/rows from dynamically created database schemas (in runtime) in SQLAlchemy? The way of altering the connection to set the current schema is not acceptable to me. I want to work with all schemas simultaneously.

I'm free to use the newest SQLAlchemy 2.0 (currently in BETA release).

Comment: Are you trying to use a set of tables all created in parallel schemas?  Like 100 tables that exist in **each** of your 5 schemas ?  So really 500 individual tables total ?  Or are there different tables in different schemas?

Comment: I think there might be performance issues so maybe include some estimates on the quantities you are dealing with, like number of schemas, number of tables, etc.

Comment: Also what database are you using ?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL, about 10 tables per schema, schema represents measurement unit (let's say laboratory, each can store data from different devices which are unified for all labs). Application is a kind of manager to organize a structure, add some components to measurement unit. So, App builds a tree in GUI where one table in public schema holds names of existing schemas, then, every schema has some tables with foreign key referencing primary key in public schema. In this way, each object (some class instanse) in the GUI tree represents some row from the table in public or other schema.

Comment: It would be possible to organize everything in one schema, but in my case, schemas are used to manage access. Also, some tables could be very big, like billions of rows (time series data). In regards to latter, I decided to use schemas also due to performance issues and, possibly, for horizontal scaling. For those big tables, however, ORM is not used. They are managed separately. ORM is for small tables holding some metadata and relations.

Comment: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/EntityName this may be an answer to my question. Seems I need to declare new classes for new schemas in runtime. As I understood, SQLAlchemy can use only one mapping for one class. Different schemas introduce additional mappings to the class. This also means that relations between schemas are not possible in SQLAlchemy. In wiki above it is written "SQLAlchemy mapping makes modifications to the mapped class, so it's not really feasible to have many mappers against the exact same class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the schema per table so I think you have to make a table and class per schema.  Here is a made up example.  I have no idea what the ramifications are of changing the mapper registry during runtime.  Especially as I have done below, mid-transaction and what would happen with threadsafety.  You could probably use a master schema list table in `public` and lock it or lock the same row across connections to syncronize the schema list and provide threadsafety when adding a schema.  I'm suprised it works.  Kind of cool.

```py
import sys

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    MetaData,
    Float,
    event,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    CreateSchema,
    Table,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry

username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


metadata = MetaData()
mapper_registry = registry()


def map_class_to_some_table(cls, table, entity_name, **mapper_kwargs):
    newcls = type(entity_name, (cls,), {})
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(newcls, table, **mapper_kwargs)
    return newcls


class Measurement(object):
    pass


units = []
cls_for_unit = {}
tbl_for_unit = {}


def add_unit(unit, create_bind=None):
    units.append(unit)
    schema_name = f"unit_{unit}"
    if create_bind:
        create_bind.execute(CreateSchema(schema_name))
    else:
        event.listen(metadata, "before_create", CreateSchema(schema_name))

    cols = [
        Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column("value", Float, nullable=False),
    ]

    # One table per schema.
    tbl_for_unit[unit] = Table("measurement", metadata, *cols, schema=schema_name)
    if create_bind:
        tbl_for_unit[unit].create(create_bind)

    # One class per schema.
    cls_for_unit[unit] = map_class_to_some_table(
        Measurement, tbl_for_unit[unit], Measurement.__name__ + f"_{unit}"
    )


for unit in ["mm", "m"]:
    add_unit(unit)


metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    # Create a value for each unit (schema).
    session.add_all([cls(value=i) for i, cls in enumerate(cls_for_unit.values())])


with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    # Read back a value for each unit (schema).
    print(
        [
            (unit, cls.__name__, cls, session.query(cls).first().value)
            for (unit, cls) in cls_for_unit.items()
        ]
    )


with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    # Add another unit, add a value, flush and then read back.
    add_unit("km", create_bind=session.bind)
    session.add(cls_for_unit["km"](value=100.0))
    session.flush()
    print(session.query(cls_for_unit["km"]).first().value)
```

### Output of last `add_unit()`

```
2022-12-16 08:16:13,446 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine CREATE SCHEMA unit_km
2022-12-16 08:16:13,446 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00015s] {}
2022-12-16 08:16:13,447 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2022-12-16 08:16:13,469 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-12-16 08:16:13,469 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE unit_km.measurement (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    value FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Ian! I also experimented with the class declaration at run-time and made a simple working example before noticing your answer, going to post it just to show an idea behind it. But your code is awesome! I learned from it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ian Wilson posted a great answer to my question which I'm going to use.

About the same time I got an idea of how it can work and would like to post it here just as a very simple example. I think this is the same mechanism behind it as posted by Ian.

This example only "reads" an object from the schema that can be referenced at runtime.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import psycopg

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg://user:password@localhost:5432/My_DB", echo=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class A(object):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column("name", String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A: {self.id}, {self.name}"

metadata_obj = MetaData(schema="my_schema") # here we create new mapping

A1 = type("A1", (A, Base), {"metadata": metadata_obj})  # here we make a new subclass with desired mapping

data = session.query(A1).all()

print(data)
```

This info helped me to come to this solution:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/EntityName
"... SQLAlchemy mapping makes modifications to the mapped class, so it's not really feasible to have many mappers against the exact same class ..."
This means a separate class must be created in runtime for each schema